# Как функцию обработчик заставить изменить глобальную переменную?

Tags: python

Есть ряд функций, которые по средством одной и той же функции обрабатывают заданные им переменные. То есть функция обработчик встроена в каждую из этих функций. Проблема в том, что функция обработчик взяв переменную в качестве параметра, изменяет ее но не передает в родительскую функцию. Таким образом, изменения не сохраняются. Если же переменную не передать параметром а задать как глобальную, тогда все сработает, но функция обработчик потеряет свою универсальность, и придется плодить ее и копипастить в каждой родительской функции, что не есть хорошо. Как все таки заставить встроенную функцию обработчик передавать изменения переменных? Пример кода ниже:

```
a = 1
b = 1
c = 1


def a_changer(a):
    changer(a)
    print(a)
    return a


def b_changer(b):
    changer(b)
    print(b)
    return b


def c_changer(c):
    changer(c)
    print(c)
    return c


def changer(subject):
    subject = 2
    print(subject)
    return subject

a_changer(a)
b_changer(b)
c_changer(c)
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

то есть задача, чтобы на выходе переменные a,b,c принтелись как 2 а не как 1

Comment: Вариант отказаться от использования глобальных переменных и переделать код без них не рассматривается?

Comment: У вас changer не будет работать. В ней никак не используется аргумент subject, вместо этого просто определяется новая переменная с таким же именем.

Comment: в смысле определять переменную непосредственно в функции?... так тоже попробовал, результат тот же - changer не передал изменение

Comment: В чём проблема, чтобы заменить `f(x)` вызов на `x = f(x)`? Опишите контекст задачи. Что вы пытаетесь добиться подобными приёмами? [Что такое «Ошибка молотка» или «Ошибка XY»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/23044)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы переменные поменяли значение, их нужно переопределить

```
def a_changer(a):
    a = changer(a)
    return a

def changer(subject):
    if subject == 1:
        subject = 2
    return subject

a = 1
a = a_changer(a)
print(a)
```

Данный код выведет на экран `2`